# Shouldn't 'without loss of generality' be mentioned here?

Tags: inner-products, proof-verification

[image]

Regarding the blocked portion my question is what if $x\ne z=y?$ Shouldn't *without loss of generality* be mentioned in the [text](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Topology_of_Metric_Spaces.html?id=ehZ_LRmG3JMC&redir_esc=y)?

Comment: Yes, that would have been more accurate.